# Elegant way to return first non null object in a list of chained callbacks

Tags: scala, functional-programming

While still beginning in Scala, I stumbled into a functional algorithmic issue. Considering the following expression :

```
def myMethod(parentObject: ParentClass) : Option[Smtg] = {
  // Case 1
  parentObject.childObject.propertyObjectA.flatmap(_.propertychildA1)
  // Case 2
  parentObject.childObject.propertyObjectB.flatmap(_.propertychildB2)
  // Case 3
  parentObject.childObject.propertyObjectC.flatmap(_.propertychildC3)
}
```

I need to return `propertychildA1` if not null, otherwise `propertychildB2` if not null, otherwise `propertychildC3`

What would be an elegant way to do this in Scala's functionnal way?

Comment: Are all the values assigned in a variable? What is the type of the expression of all the cases?

Comment: Can be assigned if need to be. The type of the expression is Option[String], and that is what is to be returned

Comment: @IsmailH what are the types of ```projectObject*```?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Those are Option[SomeClass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myMethod(parentObject: ParentClass): Option[_] = {
  val childObject = parentObject.childObject
  lazy val a = childObject.propertyObjectA.flatMap(p => Option(p.propertychildA1))
  lazy val b = childObject.propertyObjectB.flatMap(p => Option(p.propertychildB2))
  lazy val c = childObject.propertyObjectC.flatMap(p => Option(p.propertychildC3))
  a orElse b orElse c
}
```

ofc you can remove some duplication

Comment: Will a, b and c be computed before the last expression ? Or is Scala intelligent enough to compute only what is needed ?

Comment: @IsmailH a, b, c are declared as methods. so they will be computed on demand. you may use `lazy val` with almost same effect for this code. so they won't be computed if no need

Comment: I think `lazy val`s have the cost of blocking the threads. Its better to use `val`s here I believe.